# django get field name on upload_to parameter

Tags: python, django

My Model:

```
class SampleImage(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path)
```

My upload_to method on image1:

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "some_file_name" + ext

    # Here is question. How can I get 'image1' field name programatically on image_path?
    used_field_name = "image1" #It would be 'image1'     
    return os.path.join('photo/%s/%s' % (instance.__class__.__name__, used_field_name), filename)
```

If field name is "image2", used_field_name on `image_path` would be `image2`

How can I get field name on where `image_path` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Example from the docs

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')
```

---

```
>>> car.photo.name
    'cars/chevy.jpg'
```